# Closing a file python

Tags: python, file

I've read that there is a way to open a file in python with..

os.startfile('file.exe')

is there a way to close the same file when open?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the [os.startfile() doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile):

> startfile() returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status.

So, basically, no, there isn't a way to close a file opened with `startfile`.

It isn't clear from the question is whether you want to *launch* a file, or to *open* it (for reading/writing).

If you want to launch a process, subprocess is a better candidate for running other processes and controlling them through a subshell (including killing them.)

If you want to open a file for read/write, then [open()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) would be a good choice to start with.

Answer (score 0):

As the Python Wiki says this function does the following:

> Start a file with its associated application.

So the best idea would be to use `os.kill` to kill the application in which it is opened. The problem lies in identyfying what application is associated with the file of following extension and finding pid of exact instance which opened that file.

You have used .exe file in example which is executable file extension, so you probably misunderstood what this function does. What are you trying to accomplish? Are you sure it is the correct way of doing it?

If you really want to launch executable file, you should probably use `os.system()`. If you want to create a new file, write something in it and close it, look for python file operations, here are good examples: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm